# How to remove duplicate records as defined by two cells in different columns in R (or Excel)

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicate records in a list based on the COMBINATION of the values in two cells whose orders are reversed. I used melt to extract a list from a matrix, but it requires a full matrix and so each record has a duplicate. For example, my data now look like:

```
meltID   individual1   individual2   distance
42            A              B          14.0
72264         A              C          12.5
5399          C              A          12.5
92200         B              C          18.1
```

lines 72264 and 5399 are duplicates.

Is there something besides melt that would extract from a triangular matrix? Or is there some other way in R to do this?

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: If you post a matrix, we can show you how to restrict consideration to the lower or upper "triangles".

Answer (score 2):

`subset(yourData, individual < individual2)` or `subset(yourData, individual <= individual2)` if you want the diagonal.